# UITableViewController not populating tableview with NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I currently have a tab bar application in the works, and have run into a bit of a roadblock. No data is populated in the table view, When i try to load my TableViewController with records from an NSMutable array.

RootViewController methods - which is the TableViewController

```
- (id)init
{
//Call the superclass's designated initalizer
self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

if (self){

    //Populate NSMutalableArry with all pub objects 

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        [[PubStore defaultStore] createPub];
        //j = [[[[PubStore defaultStore] allPubs] objectAtIndex:i] getPubName];

    }

    //Get the tab bar item
    UITabBarItem *tbi = [self tabBarItem];

    //Give it a label
    [tbi setTitle:@"Pubs"];

    //Create a UIImage from a file
    UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"88-beermug.png"];

    //Put Image on the tab bar item
    [tbi setImage:i];




}

return self;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


return [[[PubStore defaultStore] allPubs] count];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath {
// Create an instnce of UITableViewCell, with default appearance
UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"] autorelease];

//Set the text on the cell with the description of the possession
//that is at the nth index of the possessions, where n =row this cell
//will appear in on the tableview

Pub *p = [[[PubStore defaultStore] allPubs] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
NSLog(@"Display Pub Name: %@", [p getPubName]);    
[[cell textLabel] setText: [p getPubName]];


return cell;
}
```

PubStore Methods

```
- (id)init
{

if (defaultStore) {
    //Return the old Default Store
    return defaultStore;

}

self = [super init];
if(self){
    allPubs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
return self;
}

- (NSArray *)allPubs
{
return allPubs;
}


- (Pub *)createPub
{
//* random possessions does not exist in my Pub Class
Pub *p = [Pub randomPub];
NSLog(@"New Pub: %@", p); 
[allPubs addObject:p];


return p;
}
```

Any help you could provide me would be greatly appreciated, i'm in the progress of learning objective c and this is one roadblock that i need to get passed.

Comment: Put an NSLog at your inits and check if you are actually going into those functions.

Comment: Actually, there is actually a NSLog in the createPub method, and i can see that the method is called 10 times successfully. However, when i try to read the count of the array after the for look, i get an error.         for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            [[PubStore defaultStore] createPub];
        }
         NSLog(@"Step Before%@", [[[PubStore defaultStore] allPubs] count]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the source of the issue. I was returning 0 instead of 1 in the `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` method. I mistakenly modified this method, and doing so was telling the program that there are no row sections to populate.

**Incorrect Method**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 0;
}
```

**Correct Method**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your RootViewController.init() method, you need something like this:

```
self.table.dataSource = self;
self.table.delegate = self;
```

assuming `table` is the name of your `UITableView`.

Comment: I've added the code, but it doesn't seem to have solved the issues.

Comment: Actually, there is actually a NSLog in the createPub method, and i can see that the method is called 10 times successfully. However, when i try to read the count of the array after the for look, i get an error. 

in the RootViewController init()


        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            [[PubStore defaultStore] createPub];
        }
         NSLog(@"Step Before%@", [[[PubStore defaultStore] allPubs] count]);

the NSLog thaws and error, and the program doesn't fully load.

error: thread 1 program received signal exc_bad_access

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your model,  you need to SET the defaultStore ivar somewhere. Also you shouldn't call initWithNibName from init.  You shouldn't mix initialisers

Answer (score 0):

Your tableviewcell needs a frame.

In cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"] autorelease];
 cell.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,80); // or whatever frame you want
```